# Modulus operation in Java

Tags: java, math, modulo, operation

```
int modx = 101;
int xy = -4/-3;
int answer = xy%modx;
System.out.println("answer= "+answer);
```

The program return me the answer 1 but when i check the answer in "PARI GP" the answer should be 35.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PARI/GP

What should I do to get the answer 35 in java implementation?

```
using Extended Euclidean algorithm, (**3**,101) we get (101*1) + (3*34)
GCD = 1

-4/-3 = 4/3
34*4 = 136
136%101 = 35
```

that is the best I could explain this

Comment: Best question is *why* should it return *that value* (35). If `(int)-4/(int)-3 = 1` and `1%101 = 1`. I wouldn't expect anything different from 1.

Comment: You should explain why you think that `(-4/-3) mod 101` ought to be `35`.  I can't think of any way that it could be ...

Comment: that is the question, the answer is 35

Comment: the answer that pari gp return me is 35. I am serious dude.

Comment: If you explain how could it return 35, i will upvote the question :)

Comment: MATH trolled... @newbieprogrammer is there any reason that supoorts your answer

Comment: If you want `35`, do this - `int xy = -105/-3;` Otherwise, be happy with the **ONE**.

Comment: even with float values its 1.3333334

Comment: if pari gp return 35 then stop using pari gp because that is very very wrong. Possibly pari gp uses % to mean something else? Or you put your brackets in the wrong place

Comment: @R.J Or, alternatively, `Math.log(1586013452313430l)`.

Comment: `136%101` is not the same as `1%101` !!!

Comment: I think you're trying to do something other than modulus, where did 34*4 = 136 even come from, also 136%101 does indeed (unsurprisingly) equal 35. 136%101 is not the same as (4/3)%101 because 4/3 and 136 are .... different numbers

Comment: 34 come from the Extended Euclidean algorithm to find the GCD

Comment: i did not use 34*4 in PARI GP, I merely typed -4/-3%101 and the answer equal 35

Comment: ahh! that could be taken as anything. Put some brackets in man! (-4/-3)%101, for example. But other commentators have said that PARI GP doesn't use % as a modulus operator. It which case it will never work, have you checked what % means in para GP. But do it by hand and you will see the answer is 4/3 (or 1 depending on if you round to an integer as you told java to)

Comment: P.s. why do you think that the modulus operator would find the greatest common divisor, it doesn't.

Comment: because i need to find the inverse of 3 mod 101

Comment: Im afraid the modulus operator has no inverse. See http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51619.html for details

Comment: @newbieprogrammer I don't know how PARI GP interprets `%`, but I can confirm that in `Z/(101)`, indeed `-4/-3 = 35`.

Comment: PARI/GP is a C library and this is a Java program. Not a real question.

Comment: I'm sorry but maybe in some notation -4/-3 = 35, but if you put -4/-3 into any reasonable programing language (such as Java as is being discussed here) you will get 1.3333. If you want java to interprete that notation you can't just write int xy = -4/-3 and expect it to do anything other than divide -4 by -3. This whole question has made me feel a little mad

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get `(-4/-3) mod 101` to be `35` in Java.  Or in any sensible arithmetic system ... AFAIK.

If you want a better answer, please explain how it *could* be 35 ... or show us how you got "PARI GP" to give you that answer.  (I suspect that what is really going on here is that you are using "PARI GP" incorrectly.)

---

You wrote:

> I merely typed -4/-3%101 and the answer equal 35

In fact, the PARA/GP cheat-sheet says this:

```
"output previous line, the lines before:    %, %`, %``, etc."
```

So "%" in Para GP does not mean modulus / remainder at all.  Basically, what you typed in means something completely different to what you think it means.

Comment: I have edited the question to explain the 35 to the best i can think of

Comment: You have introduced a new expression now `136%101` !!!

Comment: "Or in any sensible arithmetic system" Well, the modulo formulation is a bit icky, but in the field `Z/(101)` - where the arithmetic is arithmetic modulo 101 - you indeed have `(-4)/(-3) = 35` [since `(-3)*(-34) = 1 (mod 101)`, `(-4)/(-3) = (-4)*(-34) = 136 = 35 (mod 101)`]. Galois fields are sensible arithmetic systems. I find it not unbelievable (though surprising, admittedly) that a system for (among other things) symbolic computations would interpret it that way.

Comment: @DanielFischer - OK.  But the point is that he has misunderstood the PARA/GP language.  I admit that I was unable to read the PARA GP manuals ... due to the stupid way they are presented.  (The font metrics are all wrong when displayed on my system, and that makes the text unreadable.)

Comment: Oh, yes, I'm not denying that. Just that OP's attempt at explaining it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3) ,

```
The remainder operation for operands that are integers after binary 
numeric promotion (§5.6.2) produces a result value such that 
(a/b)*b+(a%b) is equal to a.
```

So, your expression `xy%modx(1%101)` should obey the relationship stated above, if you substitute the values you will see that to obey this relationship , `(1%101)` has to be `1`.

Answer (score 1):

PARI GP does not follow the convention of [modular arithmetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). Modulus can only be used with integer values, that's why java will cast

```
-4/-3 to (int) 1
```

As you can see

```
1 % 101 = 1
```

So java is giving you back the correct answer...

Answer (score 0):

I think this stems from not understanding the definition of modulus. In a deliberatly non mathematically rigerous way:

Modulus means how much is left after you take away as many whole amounts of a specified number, so:

```
1%5
No 5s go into 1 so answer is 1

7%5
1 lot of 5 goes into 7, so 7-1*5=2

16%5
5 lots of 5 go into 16, so 16-3*5=1
```

This is how modulus works, from this it is clear that:

```
1.3333%101 
No 101s go into 1.3333, so answer is 1.3333 (or 1 if you let java round to 1 first)
```